# What am I missing to enable connection sharing on my Linux box?

Tags: linux, nat

I'm having problem setting connection sharing in my Slackware system. I enabled rc.ip_forward:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
1
```

And I added the next iptables rule (and I've no other rules):

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE`

This is the output of `ifconfig`:

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:62:6d:91:7f:3f  
          inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6e62:6dff:fe91:7f3f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:528 errors:0 dropped:36 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:92 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:292440 (285.5 KiB)  TX bytes:32536 (31.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:349 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:349 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:27128 (26.4 KiB)  TX bytes:27128 (26.4 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:d6:4d:48:b0:cd  
          inet addr:131.114.43.177  Bcast:131.114.43.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::16d6:4dff:fe48:b0cd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:19695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18023 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9712346 (9.2 MiB)  TX bytes:3213810 (3.0 MiB)
```

Where wlan0 is the interface connected to the internet. eth0 ip address is set manually with `netconfig`, while wlan0 is assigned with dhcp by the access point.

Connected to eth0 there's a router with its own dhcp server, so I don't need to run one on my system. The router is on 192.168.1.1 and is serving address from 192.168.1.100. There's no hardware problem since I'm able to do it with Ubuntu and NetworkManager (with "shared with other" checkbox for eth0).

How can I troubleshot this?

Comment: Check iptables rules by `iptables -L` as root. Look for `Chain FORWARD`, if there is `policy DROP` and no other rules, then you should add iptables rules to allow forwarding. NOT safe, but for testing sufficient way is to set `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`

Comment: @week, Hi. Unfortunately all other chains are already on ACCEPT as default action and I've no other rules that may interfere.

Comment: Try to set default rule to `DROP` and add `iptables -A FROWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT` and `iptables -A FROWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT`.

Comment: Another thing, That router with dhcp is set to do nat also? Or why are you using 10.42.0/24 adress for eth0, if network is in 192.168.1/24?

Comment: If you have eth0 connected to WAN port of router, then check if router's wan interface is set properly to 10.42.0/24 site and has default gw to 10.42.0.1.

Comment: @week, Basically I'm trying to reproduce what Ubuntu does when setting the internet sharing through NetworkManager. It assigns 10.42.0.1 to eth0 and so I set the same ip address to be sure that wasn't the ip range the problem. However, I tried also with eth0 set on 192.168.1.10 and nothing changed. However, 192.168.1/24 is the 'router network' which is supposed to take internet connection from my computer and redistribute it to every computer connected to it. I assume the router is configured to do so as it works perfectly with Ubuntu+NetworkManager.

Comment: @week, Also, changing default policy for FORWARD chain and adding the rule doesn't change anything.

Comment: Do you have a default gateway set properly on routers dhcp server configuration? Wifi routers have defalult gw set to themselves, in this case 192.168.1.1. Just set eth0 address to 192.168.1.10.. and set default gw in routers dhcp-server config to 192.168.1.10. Ubuntu+NetworkManager in internet sharing mode probably starts it's own dhcp-server.

Comment: @week, I think you got it on previous comment. It was set to request an ip with dhcp, installing dnsmasq on slackware solved the problem. It seems Ubuntu as a dhcp features installed by default, while slackware doesn't. If you post it as an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -s 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state \
            --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```